# Return results from two tables joined by foreign key in Laravel.

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two tables in MySQL where one is referencing another.

The first one is the `users` table

[image]

The second table is the `event` table which contains the `creator_id` referencing the `id` in the users table. so `creator_id` is the foreign key.

[image]

Now my problem is how to get the name of each user that owns each column in the `event` table using laravel.

I'm clueless about how to do this. And the laravel doc I've read so far is not helping.

This is the model for the `event` table.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Auth;
use App\signupModel;


class eventModel extends Model
{
    //


      public $table = "event";

      protected $fillable = ['title', 'description', 'event_flier', 'event_logo', 'org_name', 'org_logo', 'free', 'state', 'city' ];

      public function getUser(){
        $id = Auth::user()->id;
        return users::where('id', $this->id); 

      }


}
?>
```

The model for the users is:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class signupModel extends Model
{
    //

      public $table = "users";
      protected $primaryKey = 'id';
     protected $fillable = [
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password', 'gender', 'phoneNumber', 'twitter', 'facebook', 'instagram', 'dob' 
    ];
}
```

I just want a way where each user can see his data from the `event` table when logged in using laravel.

please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An Event belongs to its Owner(User)

If you follow the core Laravel syntax, the Event model must look like this:

```
class Event extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

And the User model must be like:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function event()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Event');
    }
}
```

And if so, you can use:

`$events = App\User::find(1)->event;`

This is a common case and you may use your logic according to your relationship type. Here is the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships).

Answer (score 2):

you need to do in user model

```
public function getEvents(){
        return $this->hasOne('Your event model', 'creator_id');
      }
```

and import model in your controller and try like that

```
$events=User::with('getEvents')->get();
```

Or if you want to fetch one record you should try this in your controller

```
$events=User::find('Your Auth Id');
$creators=$events->getEvents;
```

Or you should try this one also

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->leftJoin('events', 'users.id', '=', 'events.creator_id')->where('users.id','=','Your user id')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here `belongsTo` is used return the creator of the event.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Auth;
use App\signupModel;

class eventModel extends Model
{
      public $table = "event";

      protected $fillable = ['title', 'description', 'event_flier', 'event_logo', 'org_name', 'org_logo', 'free', 'state', 'city' ];

      public function getUser(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\signupModel', 'creator_id');
      }

}
?>
```

In your controller, you can retrieve the creator of an event as follows

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\eventModel;
use App\signupModel;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $event = eventModel::find(1);
        $creator = $event->getUser;  // return user instance
        dump($creator); // for check result
        echo $creator->first_name;  //print firstname of creator
    }
}
```